# Libre Office Calc paste as column

Tags: libreoffice, copy-paste, libreoffice-calc

I want to copy data from the clipboard to a column  on Libre Office Calc

This is my data example

> 48032, 50201/C, 50286, 50285, 50254, 50253, 50252, 50251, 50250, 50248, 50206/C, 50204/C, >50202/C, 50201/C, 48031, 48030, 48029, 48028, 43364, 26471, 26470, 26469, 26463, 26460, >26458, 026, 022, 17, 19, 010, 005, 003

I tried this, selected cell A1

**Edit --> Paste Special**

[image]

I selected "**Use text import dialog**"

[image]

But all the time it pastes all in one row, How to solve this issue?

```
Version: 7.3.5.2 (x64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 184fe81b8c8c30d8b5082578aee2fed2ea847c01
CPU threads: 8; OS: Windows 10.0 Build 19044; UI render: Skia/Vulkan; VCL: win
Locale: it-IT (it_IT); UI: en-US
Calc: CL
```

Comment: Does [Rotating Tables (Transposing)](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/guide/table_rotate.html) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you with your solution work, I've found also this solution [How do I convert rows into columns (or vice versa) in Calc?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-convert-rows-into-columns-or-vice-versa-in-calc/7125/3) but link to image is broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I turn rows into columns.

This is also known as Rotating Tables or Transposing:

> In LibreOffice Calc, there is a way to "rotate" a spreadsheet so that
> rows become columns and columns become rows.
>
> - Select the cell range that you want to transpose.
> - Choose Edit - Cut.
> - Click the cell that is to be the top left cell in the result.
> - Choose Edit - Paste Special.
> - In the dialog, mark Paste all and Transpose.
> - If you now click OK the columns and rows are transposed.

Source: [Rotating Tables (Transposing)](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/si/text/scalc/guide/table_rotate.html)